# How to debug modx, which snippets, processors etc were called

Tags: debugging, modx

I need to find where some things happen during execution. Let's say, I'm looking for a line, which drops out user authorizition. It may be some processor like "security/logout", but not neccessary.

How should I debug modx revo ? debug_backtrace() gives me 30+ Mb of text, it's not real to read it.

How to watch quickly all user code, which is stored in database, during execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can turn on debug option on System Settings, or hack a bit the core:
http://www.virtudraft.com/blog/unofficial-parser-timer-for-modx-revolution.html